# Matrix mult order in Direct3D

Tags: directx, 3d

I've received two conflicting answers in terms of multiplying matrices in Direct3D to achieve results. Tutorials do state to multiply from left to right and that's fine but it's not how I would visualize it.

Here's an example:

OpenGL (reading from top to bottom):

```
GLRotatef(90.0f);
GLTranslatef(20.0f,0,0);
```

So you visualize the world axis rotating 30 degrees. Then you translate 20.0 on the now rotated x-axis so it looks like you are going up on the world y-axis.

In Direct3D, doing:

```
wm = rotatem * translatem;
```

is different. It looks like the object was just rotated at the origin and translated on the world's x-axis so it goes to the right and not up. It only works once I reverse the order and read from right to left.

Also for example, in frank luna's book on DX10, he goes into explaining how to do mirror reflections. I get all of that but when he does for example:

```
reflection_matrix = world_m * reflection_m;
```

around the xy plane, do I interpret this as first doing a the world positioning then a reflection or the opposite?

Comment: I think [this link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16011/136831)'s top answer give a good discription!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the order you are multiplying the matrices to get the composite transform matrix is reversed from what it should be. You are doing: `wm = rotatem * translatem`, which follows the order of operations you are doing for OpenGL, but for DirectX the matrix should have been `wm = translatem * rotatem`

The fundamental difference between OpenGL and DirectX arises from the fact that OpenGL treats matrices in **column major** order, while DirectX treats matrics in **row major** order.

To go from column major to row major you need to find the transpose ( swap the rows and the columns ) of the OpenGL matrix.

So, if you write `wm = rotatem * translatem` in OpenGL, then you want the transpose of that for DirectX, which is:

```
wmT = (rotatem*translatem)T = translatemT * rotatemT
```

which explains why the order of the matrix multiply has to be reversed in DirectX.

Comment: So in other words, I'm doing it right for all purposes. Do I assume then that the author meant to reflect first and then to apply the world matrix?

Comment: I would need more background to figure out the author's intent. But the difference you mention between the order of transformation between opengl and directx makes perfect sense.

Comment: Author's intent was to show how to mirror objects which is just reflection of the cube over an arbitrary xy plane. It makes sense that the reflection would be after the world transformation is performed but that would require that the matrix order should instead be: reflection_matrix * world_matrix if I read from right to left.

Comment: Just played got around to playing around and realized the order doesn't matter for a reflection in this case. Thanks though, you answered my question well.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15995026). In OpenGL, each subsequent operation is a pre-multiplication of all the operations before it, not a post-multiplication. You can see a matrix multiplication of a vector as a function evaluation.

If what you want is to first rotate a vector and then translate your rotated vector, which you in OpenGL would have solved by first calling `glRotatef` and then calling `glTranslatef`, you could express that using function calls as

```
myNewVector = translate(rotate(myOldVector))
```

The `rotate` function does this

```
rotate(anyVector) = rotationMatrix * anyVector
```

and the `translate` function does this

```
translate(anyOtherVector) = translationMatrix * anyOtherVector
```

so your equivalent expression using matrix multiplications would look like

```
myNewVector = translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * myOldVector
```

That is, your combined transformation matrix would look be `translationMatrix * rotationMatrix`.