# why does pyrr.Matrix44 translation appear to be column-major, and rotation row-major?

Tags: opengl, row-major-order

consider the following:

```
>>>Matrix44.from_translation( np.array([1,2,3]))                                                                                                        
Matrix44([[1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0],
          [1, 2, 3, 1]])

>>> Matrix44.from_x_rotation(0.5 * np.pi)                                                                                      
Matrix44([[ 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
          [ 0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0],
          [ 0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0],
          [ 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0]])
```

The translation matrix shows that the layout of the matrix is column-major, but the rotation matrix, confusingly, suggests that it is row-major, if you consider that the standard right-hand 3x3 rotation matrix around X in row-major notation reads:

```
0.0 0.0    0.0      
0.0 cos(a) -sin(a)  
0.0 sin(a) cos(a)
```

As seems to be the result returned by `from_x_rotation`.
Does anyone know if this is a bug, or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: you mean counter-clockwise?

Comment: counter-clockwise if you look in the direction of the x-axis

Comment: yes, but that's precisely the point. Convention is to rotate counterclockwise with positive angle (right hand rule) especially with a library that's interoperating with OpenGL. If you interpret the above rotation matrix column-major as is suggested by the translation matrix, then the rotation is reversed (!).

Comment: *"Convention is to rotate counterclockwise [...]"* -  that's your assumption (and it is common), but [pyrr](https://pyrr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_matrix.html) does not specify that explicitly. I know libraries that multiplied a vector to a column-major order matrix from the left ([OpenTK](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/687)) and nobody knows why.

Comment: pyrr specifies that it is geared towards OpenGL, see https://pyrr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_matrix.html "Matrices are laid out in row-major format and can be loaded directly into OpenGL". I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that the rotation is specified in a left-hand coordinate system, and that would be counter to the OpenGL specs. It is highly confusing that pyrr does seem to use either a lhs for rotations, or that it uses column-major matrices for translations and row-major matrices for rotations.

Comment: *"pyrr specifies that it is geared towards OpenGL"* - yes and no. It specifies that the resulting matrices are column major order, that's it. Don't bother about it, you can't change it. Possibly it is a mistake that was built in when the library was written. The behavior of the library can't be changed without breaking existing applications. That's an often seen issue of many different libraries.

Comment: _"The behavior of the library can't be changed without breaking existing applications. That's an often seen issue of many different libraries."_ That's true, but it puts pyrr firmly outside my company's realm of usability because it greatly enhances the chances of confusion.