# LWJGL-3: Cube not rendering

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've recently started a project with LWJGL 3 (Lightweight Java Game Library 3) and Java, and I've been trying to render a simple cube. However, my code currently displays an empty black screen.

This is my render code:

```java
public void renderObject(Camera camera, ShaderProgram shader) {
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    Matrix4f mvpMatrix = Matrix4f.multiply(projection, Matrix4f.multiply(entity.modelMatrix(), view)); 
    shader.uniformMatrix4f("mvpMatrix", mvpMatrix);
    indexBuf.bind();
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0); 
    entity.getTexturedMesh().bindTexture(); 
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, entity.getTexturedMesh().mesh.getIndexVec().size(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); 
    indexBuf.unbind();
    vao.unbind();
    shader.stop();
}
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoords;

out vec3 color;
out vec2 pass_texCoords;

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

void main(void) {

    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    color = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    pass_texCoords = texCoords;
}
```

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

in vec3 color;
in vec2 pass_texCoords;

out vec4 out_color;
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(void) {
    out_color = texture(textureSampler,pass_texCoords);
}
```

---

(FYI, Matrix4f is a custom math class that I made. )

**Remarks:** I discovered that if I change `gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)` to `glPosition = vec4(position, 1.0)`, then it renders (although I can see only one face of the cube). One can therefore infer that the problem is with `mvpMatrix`.

However, I made two other discoveries that seemed to contradict my hypothesis.

First, I printed out the `mvpMatrix` in `renderObject` and found that it was indeed correct.

Therefore, I deduced that the problem must be with the function `uniformMatrix4f()`, which was supposed to pass the uniform from the code to the shader.

To test my hypothesis, I decided to make a uniform matrix called `testMatrix`, which was just

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and added this line to the code:

```
shader.uniformMatrix4f("testMatrix", testMatrix);
```

I had also discovered that you can debug shaders by passing the value to the color.

Therefore, I changed `gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)` to `glPosition = vec4(position, 1.0)` and `out_color = texture(textureSampler,pass_texCoords)` to `out_color = vec4(color, 1.0)`.

Then I changed `color = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` to

```
color = vec3(testMatrix[0][0], testMatrix[1][1], testMatrix[2][2]);
```

If my hypothesis were correct, as I expected, then I would probably get a blank screen. However, if my hypothesis were false, the color would be `vec3(0, 1, 0)`, or green, and I would see a green square.

When I rendered it, I saw a green square, not a blank screen, which was extremely puzzling, and since I can't find any other source of the problem, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been very, VERY long since I solved this problem, but I realized I was storing the *transpose* of the matrix instead of the matrix itself when I was putting the uniform to the shader. The reason why my `color = vec3(testMatrix[0][0], testMatrix[1][1], testMatrix[2][2])` didn't work was because the matrix values I checked were all on the diagonal, which means they were unaffected.

I fixed this by simply changing the 'transposed' attribute from false to true.

```java
GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, matrixBuffer);
```

->

```java
GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, true, matrixBuffer);
```

---

More explanation:

I was using a one-dimensional array buffer to store the matrix (as this made it easier to store it into the uniform buffer).

Here is a 4x4 matrix for reference:

```
m00 m01 m02 m03
m10 m11 m12 m13
m20 m21 m22 m23
m30 m31 m32 m33
```

To convert the two-dimensional coordinates to the one-dimensional coordinates, I used this function:

```
m[x][y] -> [x + y * sz]
```

Which means that my array was mapped like this:

```
0 4  8 12
1 5  9 13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
```

I thought this was the right order. But it turns out this is exactly the transpose of the order I needed to put my matrices in!

I don't want this answer to get too lengthy, but you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717600/confusion-between-c-and-opengl-matrix-order-row-major-vs-column-major).