# Multiplication in OpenGL vertex shader using column-major matrix does not draw triangle as expected

Tags: opengl, graphics

When I use a custom column major matrix in my code, and pass it to the vertex shader, the triangle is not drawn as expected, but when I use a row major matrix, it draws the triangle in its correct position.

I googled it and found some answers related to this question:
[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717600/confusion-between-c-and-opengl-matrix-order-row-major-vs-column-major) and [this](http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/transformations2/transformations_matrices.html), but I could not understand what I'm doing wrong.

If I'm not mistaken, a row-major matrix is:

```
{ 0,  1,  2,  3,
  4,  5,  6,  7,
  8,  9, 10, 11,
  Tx, Ty, Tz, w}
```

So, using this row-major matrix, the multiplication order should be: v' = v*M.

And a column-major matrix is:

```
{ 0, 4,  8, Tx,
  1, 5,  9, Ty,
  2, 6, 10, Tz,
  3, 7, 11, w}
```

Using this column-major matrix, the multiplication order should be: v' = M*v.

Where Tx, Ty, and Tz hold the translation values for x, y and z, respectively.

Having said that, I will focus on what I think I'm having trouble with, in order to have a more compact question, but I will post an example code in the end, using GLFW and GLAD(<glad/gl.h>)

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
uniform mat4 transform;
void main()
{ 
   gl_Position = transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
};
```

These are my Mat4 struct and its functions:

```
typedef struct Mat4
{
    float data[16];
} Mat4;

// Return Mat4 identity matrix
Mat4 mat4_identity()
{
    Mat4 m = {0};
    m.data[0] = 1.0f;
    m.data[5] = 1.0f;
    m.data[10] = 1.0f;
    m.data[15] = 1.0f;
    return m;
}

// Translate Mat4 using row-major order
Mat4 mat4_row_translation(Mat4 a, float x, float y, float z)
{
    Mat4 m = mat4_identity();
    m.data[12] += x; 
    m.data[13] += y; 
    m.data[14] += z; 
    return m;
}

// Translate Mat4 using column-major order
Mat4 mat4_column_translation(Mat4 a, float x, float y, float z)
{
    Mat4 m = mat4_identity();
    m.data[3] += x; 
    m.data[7] += y; 
    m.data[11] += z; 
    return m;
}
```

This is my update_triangle function where I translate the matrix:

```
Mat4 trans = mat4_identity();
trans = mat4_column_translation(trans, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "transform");
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, trans.data);
```

Note that I'm passing GL_FALSE in glUniformMatrix4v, which tells OpenGL that the matrix is already in a column-major order.

However, when running the program, I do not get a triangle 0.5f up and 0.5f right, I get this:
[Weird triangle translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As7j7.png)

But when I use a row-major matrix and change the multiplication order in the vertex shader(v' = v*M), I get the result that I was expecting.

The vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
uniform mat4 transform;
void main()
{ 
   gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0) * transform;
};
```

The update_triangle function:

```
Mat4 trans = mat4_identity();
trans = mat4_row_translation(trans, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "transform");
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_TRUE, trans.data);
```

Note that I'm passing GL_TRUE in glUniformMatrix4v, which tells OpenGL that the matrix is not in a column-major order.

The result:
[Triangle drawn as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39VrX.png)

Here is the code in a single file, it needs to be compiled with GLFW and glad/gl.c.

Comment[0] and Comment[1](https://gen.glad.sh/) are just to help with which lines to comment together, for example: If you comment a line with "// Comment[0]" in int, you need to comment the other lines with "// Comment[0]" as well.
But in the Vertex Shader, both matrices use the same line to be drawn correct(which is why I don't understand).

If you are on linux, you can compile with: g++ -o ex example.cpp gl.c -lglfw && ./ex
(You will need to download gl.c from [Glad generator](https://gen.glad.sh/))

Code:

```
#include <glad/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Mat4 structure
typedef struct Mat4
{
    float data[16];
} Mat4;

int c = 0;

// Return Mat4 identity matrix
Mat4 mat4_identity()
{
    Mat4 m = {0};
    m.data[0] = 1.0f;
    m.data[5] = 1.0f;
    m.data[10] = 1.0f;
    m.data[15] = 1.0f;
    return m;
}

// Translate Mat4 using row-major order
Mat4 mat4_row_translation(Mat4 a, float x, float y, float z)
{
    Mat4 m = mat4_identity();
    m.data[12] += x; 
    m.data[13] += y; 
    m.data[14] += z; 
    return m;
}

// Translate Mat4 using column-major order
Mat4 mat4_column_translation(Mat4 a, float x, float y, float z)
{
    Mat4 m = mat4_identity();
    m.data[3] += x; 
    m.data[7] += y; 
    m.data[11] += z; 
    return m;
}

GLFWwindow *glfw_window;

// Window functions
int init_glfw(const char *window_title, int x, int y, int width, int height);
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput();

// Shader functions
static unsigned int compile_shader(unsigned int type, const char *source);
static unsigned int create_shader(const char *vertex_shader, const char *fragment_shader);

// Triangle functions
void init_triangle();
void draw_triangle();
void update_triangle();

unsigned int shader = -1;
unsigned int vao = -1;
unsigned int vbo = -1;

float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left  
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right 
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top   
};

const char *vshader = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "uniform mat4 transform;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    // "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0) * transform;\n"       // Comment [0] -> Inverted for column-major
    "   gl_Position = transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"       // Comment [1] -> Inverted for column-major
    "}\0";

const char *fshader = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

int main()
{
    int result = init_glfw("LearnOpenGL", 0, 0, 800, 600);
    if(result != 0)
        return result;
    
    init_triangle();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glfw_window))
    {
        // input
        processInput();

        // Update triangle vertices
        update_triangle();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw triangle example
        draw_triangle();

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        glfwSwapBuffers(glfw_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// My confusion is here
void update_triangle()
{
    Mat4 trans = mat4_identity();

    trans = mat4_column_translation(trans, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);    // Comment [0]
    // trans = mat4_row_translation(trans, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);       // Comment [1]

    // Print Mat4
    if(c == 0)
    {
        // TODO: Remove this
        printf("==== Trans: ====\n");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            printf("%.2f, ", trans.data[i-1]);
            if(i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
                printf("\n");
        }
        c++;
    }

    unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "transform");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, trans.data);      // Comment [0]
    // glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_TRUE, trans.data);       // Comment [1]
}

// Window functions
int init_glfw(const char *window_title, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
     // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    glfw_window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, window_title, NULL, NULL);
    if (glfw_window == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfw_window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(glfw_window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    int version = gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress);
    printf("Current GL loaded: %d.%d\n", GLAD_VERSION_MAJOR(version), GLAD_VERSION_MINOR(version));

    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput()
{
    if(glfwGetKey(glfw_window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(glfw_window, true);
}

/* Default Compilation for Shader */
static unsigned int compile_shader(unsigned int type, const char *source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* msg = (char*) alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, msg);
        printf("Vertex / Fragment Shader Failed:\n %s", msg);
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }
    return id;
}

static unsigned int create_shader(const char *vertex_shader, const char *fragment_shader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = compile_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader);
    unsigned int fs = compile_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment_shader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

// Triangle functions
void init_triangle()
{
    shader = create_shader(vshader, fshader);
    printf("shader=%d", shader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    printf("vao=%d", vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    printf("vbo=%d\n", vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);         // Using this vbo
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), NULL);
}

void draw_triangle()
{
    glUseProgram(shader);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

This is my first question in this forum, so please let me know if there is anything missing.

Comment: *"If I'm not mistaken, a row-major matrix is: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ..."* - Why do you think that this is a row-major matrix? That is just a matter of interpretation. Column-major matrix simply means that values 0-3 are the 1st column of the matrix, values 4-7 are the 2nd, and so on. This is the way the values in the array are interpreted to form a matrix. Just because you write the values in a row does not mean that it has to be a row in the matrix.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wanted to point out that the last column of a colum-major matrix has the translation information, and that the last row of row-major matrix has this information. Perhaps I'm seeing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So many people use row-major or transposed matrices, that they forget that matrices are not naturally oriented that way. So they see a translation matrix as this:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
x y z 1
```

This is a **transposed translation matrix**. That is not what a normal translation matrix looks like. The translation goes in the 4th *column*, not the fourth row. Sometimes, you even see this in textbooks, which is utter garbage.

It's easy to know whether a matrix in an array is row or column-major. If it's row-major, then the translation is stored in the 3, 7, and 11th indices. If it's column-major, then the translation is stored in the 12, 13, and 14th indices. Zero-base indices of course.

Your confusion stems from believing that you're using column-major matrices when you're in fact using row-major ones.

The statement that row vs. column major is a notational convention only is entirely true. The mechanics of matrix multiplication and matrix/vector multiplication are the same regardless of the convention.

What changes is the meaning of the results.

A 4x4 matrix after all is just a 4x4 grid of numbers. It doesn't *have* to refer to a change of coordinate system. However, once you assign *meaning* to a particular matrix, you now need to know what is stored in it and how to use it.

Take the translation matrix I showed you above. That's a valid matrix. You could store that matrix in a `float[16]` in one of two ways:

```
float row_major_t[16] =    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, x, y, z, 1};
float column_major_t[16] = {1, 0, 0, x, 0, 1, 0, y, 0, 0, 1, z, 0, 0, 0, 1};
```

However, I said that this translation matrix is wrong, because the translation is in the wrong place. I specifically said that it is transposed relative to the standard convention for how to build translation matrices, which ought to look like this:

```
1 0 0 x
0 1 0 y
0 0 1 z
0 0 0 1
```

Let's look at how these are stored:

```
float row_major[16] =    {1, 0, 0, x, 0, 1, 0, y, 0, 0, 1, z, 0, 0, 0, 1};
float column_major[16] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, x, y, z, 1};
```

Notice that `column_major` is *exactly the same* as `row_major_t`. So, if we take a *proper* translation matrix, and store it as column-major, it is the same as transposing that matrix and storing it as row-major.

That is what is meant by being only a notational convention. There are really two sets of conventions: memory storage and transposition. Memory storage is column vs row major, while transposition is normal vs. transposed.

If you have a matrix that was generated in row-major order, you can get the same effect by transposing the column-major equivalent of that matrix. And vice-versa.

Matrix multiplication can only be done one way: given two matrices, in a specific order, you multiply certain values together and store the results. Now, `A*B != B*A`, but the actual source code for `A*B` is the same as the code for `B*A`. They both run the same code to compute the output.

The matrix multiplication code does not care whether the matrices happen to be stored in column-major or row-major order.

The same *cannot* be said for vector/matrix multiplication. And here's why.

Vector/matrix multiplication is a falsehood; it cannot be done. However, you *can* multiply a matrix by another matrix. So if you pretend a vector is a matrix, then you can effectively do vector/matrix multiplication, simply by doing matrix/matrix multiplication.

A 4D vector can be considered a column-vector or a row-vector. That is, a 4D vector can be thought of as a 4x1 matrix (remember: in matrix notation, the row count comes first) or a 1x4 matrix.

But here's the thing: Given two matrices A and B, `A*B` is only defined if the number of columns of A is the same as the number of rows of B. Therefore, if A is our 4x4 matrix, B must be a matrix with 4 rows in it. Therefore, you cannot perform `A*x`, where x is a *row-vector*. Similarly, you cannot perform `x*A` where x is a column-vector.

Because of this, most matrix math libraries make this assumption: if you multiply a vector times a matrix, you really mean to do the multiplication that actually *works*, not the one that makes no sense.

Let us define, for any 4D vector x, the following. `C` shall be the column-vector *matrix* form of `x`, and `R` shall be the row-vector *matrix* form of `x`. Given this, for any 4x4 matrix A, `A*C` represents matrix multiplying A by the column-vector `x`. And `R*A` represents matrix multiplying the row-vector `x` by A.

But if we look at this using strict matrix math, we see that these are *not equivalent*. `R*A` *cannot* be the same as `A*C`. This is because a row-vector is not the same thing as a column-vector. They're not the same matrix, so they do not produce the same results.

However, they are related in one way. It is true that `R != C`. However, it is also true that `R = CT`, where <sup>T</sup> is the transpose operation. The two matrices are transposes of each other.

Here's a funny fact. Since vectors are treated as matrices, they too have a column vs. row-major storage question. The problem is that they both *look the same*. The array of floats is the same, so you can't tell the difference between R and C just by looking at the data. The *only* way to tell the difference is by how they are used.

If you have any two matrices A and B, and A is stored as row-major and B as column-major, multiplying them is **completely meaningless**. You get nonsense as a result. Well, not really. Mathematically, what you get is the equivalent of doing `ATB`. Or `ABT`; they're mathematically identical.

Therefore, matrix multiplication only makes sense if the two matrices (and remember: vector/matrix multiplication is just matrix multiplication) are stored in the same major ordering.

So, is a vector column-major or row-major? It is both and neither, as stated before. It is column major only when it is used as a column matrix, and it is row major when it is used as a row matrix.

Therefore, if you have a matrix A which is column major, `x*A` means... nothing. Well, again, it means `x*AT`, but that's not what you really wanted. Similarly, `A*x` does transposed multiplication if `A` is row-major.

Therefore, the order of vector/matrix multiplication *does* change, depending on your major ordering of the data (and whether you're using transposed matrices).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! Just to clarify to myself, as you said, I'm just moving my Tx, Ty and Tz to the last column for my **row-major matrix**. So even though my matrix is M = { { 1, 0, 0, Tx},  {0, 1,  0, Ty}, {0, 0,  1, Tz}, {0, 0,  0, w}}, the memory is stored as M = {1, 0, 0, Tx, 0, 1, 0, Ty, 0, 0, 1, Tz, 0, 0, 0, w}, which is not what OpenGL is expecting, and then I need to transpose M = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {Tx, Ty,  Tz, w}}, so that the memory can be stored as M = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, Tx, Ty, Tz, w}, is that correct?