# What is wrong with my matrix stack implementation (OpenGL ES 2.0)?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, coordinate-transformation

I am porting my OpenGL 1.1 application to OpenGL ES 2.0 and am writing a wrapper to implement the OpenGL 1.1 functions. My code seems to work fine until I start calling `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`. I think my understanding of how these should be implemented is incorrect.

Do I compute the final rotate/translate/scale before pushing it back on the stack? Should I keep only one modelview matrix (instead of separating it into three)? Are the transforms applied in the correct order?

Here is the code for my tranformation matrices

```
static std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
static std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat>> rotationMatrixStack;
static std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat>> scalingMatrixStack;

static std::vector<GLfloat> rotationMatrix =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

static std::vector<GLfloat> scalingMatrix =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

static std::vector<GLfloat> translationMatrix =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

static std::vector<GLfloat> orthographicMatrix =
{
    .0025f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.0f, .0025f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

void glTranslatef (GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    float translation[] = 
    {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   x,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   y,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   z,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    multiplyMatrix(translation , &translationMatrix[0], &translationMatrix[0]);
}
void glScalef (GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    float scaling[] = 
    {
           x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,    y, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,    z, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    multiplyMatrix(scaling , &scalingMatrix[0], &scalingMatrix[0]);
}
void glRotatef (GLfloat angle, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
    GLfloat radians = angle * M_PI/180;
    float zRotation[] = 
    {
        cos(radians), -sin(radians), 0.0f, 0.0f,
        sin(radians),  cos(radians), 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,          0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f,          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    multiplyMatrix(zRotation , &rotationMatrix[0], &rotationMatrix[0]);
    glTranslatef(x,y,z);
}

void glLoadIdentity (void)
{
    rotationMatrix, scalingMatrix, translationMatrix = 
    {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };
}

void multiplyMatrix(float* a, float* b, float* product)
{
    int a_heigth = 4;
    int a_width = 4;
    int b_heigth = 4;
    int b_width = 4;
    int product_heigth = a_heigth;
    int product_width = b_width;

    float intermediateMatrix[product_heigth * product_width] = {0};
    for (int product_row = 0; product_row < product_heigth; product_row++)
    {
        for (int product_column = 0; product_column < product_width; product_column++)
        {
            float value = 0;
            //std::cout << "r[" << (product_row*product_width) + product_column << "] = ";
            for (int multiplication_index = 0; multiplication_index < a_width ; multiplication_index++)
            {
                value += a[(product_row * a_width) + multiplication_index] * b[product_column + (b_heigth * multiplication_index)];
                //std::cout << "( a[" << (product_row * a_width) + multiplication_index << "] * b[" << product_column + (b_heigth * multiplication_index) << "] ) + ";
            }
            //std::cout << std::endl;
            intermediateMatrix[(product_row*product_width) + product_column] = value;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < product_heigth * product_width; i++)
    {
        product[i] = intermediateMatrix[i];
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the matrix stack

```
static std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat>> translationMatrixStack;
void glPushMatrix()
{
    rotationMatrixStack.push_back(rotationMatrix);
    scalingMatrixStack.push_back(scalingMatrix);
    translationMatrixStack.push_back(translationMatrix);
}

void glPopMatrix()
{
    rotationMatrix = rotationMatrixStack.back();
    scalingMatrix = scalingMatrixStack.back();
    translationMatrix = translationMatrixStack.back();

    rotationMatrixStack.pop_back();
    scalingMatrixStack.pop_back();
    translationMatrix.pop_back();
}
```

And here is the vertex shader code

```
attribute highp vec4    myVertex;
uniform mediump mat4    orthographicMatrix;
uniform mediump mat4    translationMatrix;
uniform mediump mat4    scalingMatrix;
uniform mediump mat4    rotationMatrix;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position =   orthographicMatrix * translationMatrix * scalingMatrix * rotationMatrix * ( myVertex) ;
}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a separate matrix stack for rotation, translation and scaling. In OpenGL there is one matrix stack for each matrix mode (See [**`glMatrixMode`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)). The matrix modes are `GL_MODELVIEW`, `GL_PROJECTION`, and `GL_TEXTURE`.

See the documentation of [**`glTranslate`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml):

> `glTranslate` produces a translation by `x y z` . The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by this translation matrix, with the product replacing the current matrix.

the documentation of [**`glRotate`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml):

> `glRotate` produces a rotation of angle degrees around the vector `x y z` . The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by a rotation matrix with the product replacing the current matrix.

and the documentation of [**`glScale`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml):

> `glScale`produces a nonuniform scaling along the `x`, `y`, and `z` axes. The three parameters indicate the desired scale factor along each of the three axes.
>   The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by this scale matrix.

This means you need one matrix stack, and all operations operate on the same matrix stack.

Note, a matrix multiplication `C = A * B` works like this:

```
Matrix4x4 A, B, C;

// C = A * B
for ( int k = 0; k < 4; ++ k )
    for ( int j = 0; j < 4; ++ j )
        C[k][j] = A[0][l] * B[k][0] + A[1][j] * B[k][1] + A[2][j] * B[k][2] +  A[3][j] * B[k][3];
```

A 4*4 matrix looks like this:

```
  c0  c1  c2  c3            c0  c1  c2  c3
[ Xx  Yx  Zx  Tx ]        [  0   4   8  12 ]     
[ Xy  Yy  Zy  Ty ]        [  1   5   9  13 ]     
[ Xz  Yz  Zz  Tz ]        [  2   6  10  14 ]     
[  0   0   0   1 ]        [  3   7  11  15 ]
```

And the memory image of a 4*4 matrix looks like this:

```
[ Xx, Xy, Xz, 0, Yx, Yy, Yz, 0, Zx, Zy, Zz, 0, Tx, Ty, Tz, 1 ]
```

This means you have to adapt your matrix operations:

```
static std::vector<std::vector<GLfloat>> modelViewMatrixStack;

static std::vector<GLfloat> modelViewMatrix{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

void multiplyMatrix( float A[], float B[], float P[] )
{
    float C[16];
    for ( int k = 0; k < 4; ++ k ) {
        for ( int l = 0; l < 4; ++ l ) {
            C[k*4+j] =
                A[0*4+j] * B[k*4+0] +
                A[1*4+j] * B[k*4+1] +
                A[2*4+j] * B[k*4+2] +
                A[3*4+j] * B[k*4+3];
        }
    }
    std::copy(C, C+16, P);
}
```

```
void glTranslatef( GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z )
{
    float translation[]{
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        x,    y,    z,    1.0f };

    multiplyMatrix(&modelViewMatrix[0], translation, &modelViewMatrix[0]);
}

void glScalef( GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z )
{
    float scaling[]{
        x,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, y,    0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, z,    0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    multiplyMatrix(&modelViewMatrix[0], scaling, &modelViewMatrix[0]);
}

void glRotatef( GLfloat angle, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z )
{
    float radians = angle * M_PI/180;
    float c = cos(radians);
    float s = sin(radians);

    float rotation[16]{
       x*x*(1.0f-c)+c,   x*y*(1.0f-c)-z*s, x*z*(1.0f-c)+y*s, 0.0f,
       y*x*(1.0f-c)+z*s, y*y*(1.0f-c)+c,   y*z*(1.0f-c)-x*s, 0.0f,
       z*x*(1.0f-c)-y*s  z*y*(1.0f-c)+x*s, z*z*(1.0f-c)+c,   0.0f,
       0.0f,             0.0f,             0.0f,             1.0f };

    multiplyMatrix(&rotationMatrix[0], rotation, &rotationMatrix[0]);
}
```

See further:

- [GLSL 4×4 Matrix Fields](http://www.geeks3d.com/20141114/glsl-4x4-matrix-mat4-fields/)
- [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)
- [Data Type (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL))

Comment: Some of my working OpenGL code becomes distorted when I do this. It appears that OpenGL would apply transformation in the order of rotate -> scale -> translate regardless of which order the user called the functions. With one modelView matrix, how do I still guarantee this order to preserve this behavior?

Comment: I think I need to do all of my matrix math in column major order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993339/opengl-order-of-matrix-transformations

Comment: In coIumn major order, is the correct order for the shader still gl_Position = orthographicMatrix * modelViewMatrix * myVertex

Comment: @j_omega Yes, it is `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0);`